# Certain file formats corrupted over FTP

Tags: java, sockets, file-handling

I Have written a server and a client to implement FTP and if i create text files and send them they work fine . but as soon as i send files of other formats the received file on the clients  end is a corrupted one. here the code where i,m sending the file

```
           try
           {
              fis=new FileInputStream(filenm);
           }

           catch(FileNotFoundException exc)
           {
              filexists=false;
              System.out.println("FileNotFoundException:"+exc.getMessage());
           }
           if(filexists)
           {
               System.out.println("sent");
               sendBytes(fis, output);
               fis.close();
            }

private static void sendBytes(FileInputStream f,OutputStream op)throws Exception
 {
  byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
  int bytes=0;

  while((bytes=f.read(buffer))!=-1)
  {
   op.write(buffer,0,bytes);
  }
 }
```

fis - FileInputStream object
output - OutputStream object (Socket.getOutputStream())

and the client code is:

```
File f=new File(dir,"file2");
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);
DataOutputStream dops=new DataOutputStream(fos);
System.out.println("2nd Stage");
while(done)
{
  fc2=br.read();
  if(fc2==-1)
  {
    done=false;
  }
  else
  {
       dops.write(fc2);
  }
}
fos.close();
System.out.println("File Recieved");
```

am i using the right streams ?

Comment: Did you remember to set the transfer mode to IMAGE?

Comment: Why do you use different reading loops in the server and client? The server code is much better.

Comment: @raymond sorry if this sounds stupid but how do i set the transfer mode to image also ill be transfering more types of file than image files

Comment: You use the `TYPE` command. See RFC 959.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are sending Binary files in ASCII mode.

Send **TYPE I** instead of **TYPE A** on the control channel before you set up the data channel by sending the **PORT** or **PASV** command.